# Storing access token and refresh token in KeyChain

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychainitemwrapper

I would like to know how to effectively store the access token, refresh tokens and their expirations in the iOS keychain.

All the examples I have seen seem to store only one key-value combination. How do we store multiple key values for one keychain identifier?

If there is a better way to store the above, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first want to build a NSDictionary with the key/values you want.
Next, you could use something like [Lockbox](https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox) to store that NSDictionary to the keychain, using the provided `setDictionary:forKey:` interface.

**UPDATE:** To change values stored in that dictionary, you only have to pass by a `NSMutableDictionary` (that's the common way of doing):

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[LockBox dictionaryForKey:@"YourRefreshTokenDictionaryKey"] mutableCopy];
mutableDict[@"access_token"] = @"NewAccessToken";
[LockBox setDictionary:mutableDict forKey:@"YourRefreshTokenDictionaryKey"];
```

FYI, a `NSMutableDictionary` is a subclass of `NSDictionary`, so it's safe to save that back directly to the keychain!

Comment: Looks like i wont be able to modify the dictionary..(access token is going to change and so does the refresh token) Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @cableload : I've added how to edit the dictionary and save it back in my answer!

Comment: @ruffel, thats what i was looking for..Thanks! This will work !